# How can I replace one DOM element with an array of jQuery objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of jQuery objects that I built and which have events attached to them.

```
var obs = [];
for(var i=0;i<100;i++) {
  var j = jQuery('<div></div>');
  j.click(function() { console.log('Clicked ' + i); });
  obs.push(j);
}
```

My HTML is:

```
<div id="replaceme"></div>
```

How do I replace the div on the page with all the jQuery objects in my array?  I don't want to concatenate their HTML because I want to preserve the event handlers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace an element with an array of jQuery elements by doing this:

```
$(theElement).replaceWith(theArryaOfjQueryElements);
```

In your case, this is:

```
$('#replaceme').replaceWith(objs);
```

See the [`jQuery.replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) method.

---

BTW you have an error here:

```
j.click(function() { console.log('Clicked ' + i); });
```

This will always print `Clicked 100`. The reason is that your function closes a reference to `i`, not to it's value. So if `i` is modified before this function is called, the function will see the new value of `i`.

You should do this instead:

```
 (function(i) {
     j.click(function() { console.log('Clicked ' + i); });
 }(i));
```

Comment: Wow... it works.  But in the documentation I didn't see where it accepts an array of jQuery objects.  I'm familiar with a jQuery-array being used here, but didn't realize a javascript array of jQuery would work the same.

Comment: jQuery actually seems to accept anything that has a length property everywhere it expects a jQuery object, and always wraps it. (You can create a jQuery object from an array: `$([...])`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `replaceWith` jQuery method which replaces each element in the set of matched elements with the provided new content.

```
var $obj = jQuery();//This will create an empty jQuery object
for(var i=0;i<100;i++) {
  var j = jQuery('<div></div>');
  j.click(function() { console.log('Clicked ' + i); });
  $obj.add(j);//Using add method to add the jQuery object into $obj
}

$("#replaceme").replaceWith($obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var obs = [];
for(var i=0;i<100;i++) {
    var j = jQuery('<div></div>');
    j.click(function() { console.log('Clicked ' + i); });
    obs.push(j);
}

$('#replaceme').html(objs);
/* or */
$('#replaceme').replaceWith(objs);
```

Answer (score 0):

I read, that creating all elements at once is much faster then creating one by one. With the click function, you could count all previous siblings to get the index:

```
var str = ''
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  str += '<div></div>';
}
var elem = jQuery(str);
elem.click(function() { console.log('clicked '+jQuery(this).prevAll().length); });

jQuery('#replaceme').replaceWith(elem);
```